# What does this paraphrase mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, paraphrasing

Source:http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-editorials/hit-wicket-down-under-modi-scores-big-for-congress-by-likening-gods-own-country-to-pirates-own-somalia/

> So Modi may also have ended up aggravating many tourists in thrall of Kerala’s **smiling and highly literate and clean and green joys.**

What bold part means , green and literate joys?

What speaker intends to say by

> Hit Wicket Down Under

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hit Wicket

it is a cricketing reference: a batman may get himself out by accidentally hitting his wicket with his bat. So Prime Minister Modi has accidentally damaged his cause, he had good intentions but said something that offended or upset his audience, or so the journalist claims. He damaged his own cause just as a batsman may get himself out Hit Wicket.

> Down Under

I would expect to refer to the location where Mr Modi made his speech, to an English person Down Under normally refers to Australia, but I'm guessing that in India there is a different implication.

As for the other phrase:

> Kerala’s smiling and highly literate and clean and green joys.

This reads as a rather enthusiastic description of Kerala.

> Kerala's joys.

Clearly means there are joyful things to be found in Kerala.

> Kerala's smiling joys

So we get an impression of the people.

> Kerala's smiling and highly literate joys

So the people are well-educated too

> Kerala’s clean joys.

The place is nicely kept too.

> Kerala’s clean and green joys.

and there is nice vegetation.

Put it all together:

> Kerala’s smiling and highly literate and clean and green joys.

Personally, I would break this down into two or more sentences.